# Change specific value from multiindex in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, rename, multi-index

I cannot find any easy way to change a specific value of a multiindex dataframe.

I have a dataframe with a two levels index (ID, Date). I have noticed that some dates for a specific ID are wrong and would like to change it.

My initial guess was to do something like :

```
df.rename(index={('ID_xx','wrongDate'):('ID_xx','correctDate')}, inplace=True)
```

But it does not work due to the process behind rename (level and labels lists)

Any thought on how would to correct this wrong index value ?

Thanks !

Comment: can u share some data, along with ur expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks to @jezrael for poiting me to a solution.

Comment: Not nice answer, but really complicated what need...

Comment: for other with same problem : `L = [(0,9) if x == (0,1) else x for x in df.index]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L, names=df.index.names)`